# How to get id of an element with 'onClick ' function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to catch an integer id with "onClick" function. And send it database with ajax. And display all related information to this id in alert box.

```
<button class="show">Show Popup</button>

  <div class="Popup Confirm">
    <input type="text" id="id" />
    <button type="button" onclick="getId(document.getElementById('id').innerHTML);">Get</button>
  </div>

<script>
$('.show').click(function(){    
$(".Popup").show();
$("#id").val(4);
});

function getId(id = null) {
if(id) {        
    $.ajax({
        url: 'abc.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {id: id},
        dataType: 'text',
        success:function(response) {
            alert(id);
        }
    }); 
} 
else {
    // error messages
     alert("No id selected");
    } 
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you bind the click event to the button using jQuery's `.click()` instead of using inline JS?

Comment: `$ ajax` has got two callbacks, `success` and `error` (?) you should use both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```html
    <button type="button" onclick="getId(document.getElementById('id').innerHTML);">Get</button>
```

you should use:

```html
    <button type="button" onclick="getId(document.getElementById('id').value);">Get</button>
```

The input field value is available through the `value` property, not `innerHTML`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3cjh6bf0/

Comment: I can't do the ajax thing in jsfiddle. If you modify your code it should work (if the server side is OK).

Comment: For practice good, but i wouldn't recommend above method though.

Comment: There are a lot of things in the code I wouldn't recommend, but I tried to stick to the very problem at hand.